# How can I get a Twitter list ID from it's slug?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I have a list slug for example twitter.com/guidomb/iphone. I want to the get the list ID. How can I do that? I'm doing an application in Java using Twitter4J and the method getUserListStatuses() requires a list ID and I have a list slug. Is there a cool way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not using twitter4j but based on the Twitter API
You can fetch the URL: http://api.twitter.com/1/guidomb/lists/iphone.json
to get the list ID.

I'm not sure why the function `showUserList(java.lang.String listOwnerScreenName, int id)` does not have a version to take a string slug instead of the integer id because in the Twitter API, the id and slug is interchangeable and can be both used to fetch the list information.
http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/:user/lists/:id

Answer (score -1):

getAllUserLists returns List of UserLists and you can get the list id from UserList#getId().
http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/Twitter.html#getAllUserLists(java.lang.String)

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to iterate over the user's list